# How do I calculate my Jump when combined with Charging speed

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, charge

What speed I may take to calculate my jump bonus if I'm charging?

Charge gives me twice speed. For example I'm a dwarf and I have 20 speed. If I'm going to use Charge my speed is 40. To calculate Jump do I take -6(20speed-30speed = -10) or +4(40-30)  penalty/bonus to jump check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## You take a -6, because your speed is 20, regardless of the action taken to move or distance actually moved.

> **Your Jump check is modified by your speed.** If your speed is 30 feet then no modifier based on speed applies to the check. If your speed is less than 30 feet, you take a -6 penalty for every 10 feet of speed less than 30 feet. If your speed is greater than 30 feet, you gain a +4 bonus for every 10 feet beyond 30 feet.

You use whatever your speed is. Your speed is a more or less static thing, and is not depending on any specific actions you are taking. For example, your Jump bonus does not go up when you take the Run action, because your speed is still 20ft, you just move 4 times your speed in a single round.

Likewise, charging does not increase your speed, it only changes the amount of distance you cover while still getting to make an attack.

(Unless you have a Feat or something that says "Your speed is increased by 20ft while charging", but I have never heard of such a thing)

Comment: Also, you can't charge if there is any obstacle in your way. I would say that anything that requires a jump check is such an obstacle.

Comment: its question about LeapAttack feat
http://dndtools.pw/feats/complete-adventurer--54/leap-attack--1741/

Comment: Leap Attack does not mention that it changes your speed, so you use your regular speed (which is 20ft).

Comment: Thx. its clear. so its happend because i have problem with my english

Comment: @user1195154: Don't we all :)

Comment: @eimyr While the core rules don't mention it, the *Rules Compendium* allows some skills to be used while charging so that a charge can be made despite obstacles.